# Conditional IF in AS3

Tags: actionscript-3

this is the relevant part of my code. it will compare if you have writen in the input box the same value of the par variable. it basically works as a password verifier. However, it says that the password is wrong even with me writing it correctly. Could someone lend a hand?

```
 var par:String =(e.target.data.firstname); //this will set the par variable to some     text

 var kobol;

 kobol = textfield2.text // this will set the kobol var to the input text value

    trace(kobol);//this is just for me to make sure that this value was the same of the        par var

   trace(par);//this is just for me to make sure that this value was the same of the         kobol var

if (kobol == par) 
{ 
trace("got it"); 
} 
else 
{ 
trace(fail); 
}
```

Comment: What does your `trace` calls output? The actual same value?

Comment: @h2ooooooo you mean , same **value**

Comment: @Cherniv Yes, indeed.

Comment: those first trace calls outputs the two variables, kobol ( the text input by the user) and par, the other variable. I made those calls just to make sure they were identical. And they are. My if statement say otherwise, however, and i dunno why.

Comment: My guess is that they are not identical. What does `trace(escape(kobol))` and `trace(escape(par))` output? Most likely not the same value.

Comment: EDIT: in fact they output different values: pudimdepassas and
pudimdepassas%0A%0A

Comment: @user3037662 You're most likely dealing with invisible characters. Just to make sure, does `trace(kobol.length)` and `trace(par.length)` output their *actual* length, or a number that's a little higher than it should be?

Comment: You were right. They were not identical. Dunno why tought. They have outputed slightly different values when i ran the trace(escape) calls. The outputed values were: pudimdepassas and pudimdepassas%0A%0A

Comment: In your code, does kobol really not have a type?  Maybe that is part of the problem, also, you can StringUtil.trim to remove the whitespace, %0A is a newline character

Comment: Question solved. Thank you guys.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

After using `trace(escape(str))` you can see that one value ends with `%0A%0A`. `0A` is hexadecimal for 10 which is the decimal ASCII value for a line feed (`\n`). This means that one of your strings have two LF (`\n`) characters at the end of it. You can strip it them off with regex:

```
str = str.replace(/\n+$/, "");
```

If you wish to strip any white-space off the end, you can do so with `\s`:

```
str = str.replace(/\s+$/, "");
```

If you wish to strip white-space off in the beginning and the end, you can use the following:

```
str = str.replace(/^\s+|\s+$/, "");
```

`\s` is the same as `[\t\r\n ]` so it includes TAB, CR, LF and spaces.

Answer (score 1):

Orrr you can just StringUtil.trim() your strings